# Dynamically resizing the width of a div that contains Jstree Tree

Tags: jquery, css, jstree

I've got the following layout:

```
<div id="tree" class="jstree"></div>
```

And it generates a jstree that has multiple levels of `ul` and `li` elements. I've got `overflow:auto` set so that as I expand or collapse the items, scrollbars appears. What I would like to happen is dynamically resize the width of `#tree` so that as you are expanding items, it will resize so that there would be no horizontal scroll.

Here is a fiddle describing what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/0xwg3c2c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` to have the element resize based on it's content.

```
.container {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px black solid;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the CSS, use the min-width, and min-height properties like this:

```
.container {
    border: 1px black solid;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: On your example you have a min-width set to 150px, however the width that the border is around is clearly larger than 150px. It spans across the whole page. How do I have the width start at something like 150px and expand from there.

Comment: Make the container position absolute. I edited my response and the jsfiddle accordly. I hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. Apparently I can use inline-block as the display. More than one way to skin a pig, I suppose.

Comment: Keep in mind absolutely positioning elements should be avoided unless explicitly needed.